# How do I fill NA in specific column with the sum of two values?

Tags: python

I want to impute missing values I have in a 'Roll_time' column. I created a 'Time_diff' column that has the difference between 'Roll_time' and 'Notif_time' for the rows that have all the data.

I'm trying to use the sum of the mean 'Time_diff' and the respective 'Notif_time' for the row to impute into the missing 'Roll_time' values.

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
df['Roll_time'].fillna(df['Time_diff'].mean() + df['Notif_time'])   

# df['Time_diff'] = (df['Roll_time'] - df['Notif_time']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I already created the 'Time_diff' column and it has timedelta values. What I'm having trouble with is finding the mean for the 'Time_diff' column and adding that to the 'Notif_time' values for each row that's missing 'Roll_time'.

Comment: try this 
df['Roll_time'].fillna(df['Time_diff'].mean() + df['Notif_time'])

Comment: This is what I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'datetime.time'" I tried converting the delta 'Time_diff' to datetime, but it the error tells me I can't.

Comment: Then you need to change Time_diff format with below
df['Time_diff'] = df['Time_diff'].days() 
or
df['Time_diff'] = df['Time_diff'].secondes()

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'". The "Notif_time" is an object and the "Time_diff" is a timedelta64[ns]